# Dynamic memory allocation of struct in c

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, structure

Code:

```
struct T_Name
{
   char *First;
   char *Middle;
   char *Last; 
};

struct T_FullName
{ 
   char *Title;
   struct T_Name Name; 
   char *Suffix;
};

struct T_Person
{ 
   struct T_FullName *FullName;
   int Age;
   char Sex;
   struct T_Person *BestFriend;
};

typedef struct T_Person *ptrPerson;

ptrPerson pFriend[10];

struct T_Person Person[10];
```

How could I write necesarry code to dynamically allocate memory to store a value in pFriend[2]->FullName->Name.First?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the length of the first name to store,

```
// Allocate memory for FullName.
Person[2].FullName = malloc(sizeof(T_FullName);

// Allocate memory for the first name.
Person[2].FullName->Name.First = malloc(FIRSTNAME_LENGTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **pFriend** is a pointer variable, so you have to allocate memory for pointer variable first. Then after allocation of the memory again your **FullName** is pointer type , so we need to allocate memory for it, Finally your **Name** member in **FullName** is not a pointer type , so you can use **First** from **Name** with a **.** operator to allocate memory for it.

```
//Allocate space for T_Person
pFriend[2] = malloc(sizeof(T_Person);
//Allocate space for FullName
pFriend[2]->FullName = malloc(sizeof(T_FullName);
//Allocate space for First Name
pFriend[2]->FullName->Name.First = malloc(sizeof(urstringlength));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pFriend[2] = malloc( sizeof *pFriend[2] );
pFriend[2]->FullName = malloc( sizeof *pFriend[2]->FullName );
pFriend[2]->FullName->First = malloc( strlen(the_name) + 1 );
strcpy(pFriend[2]->FullName->First, the_name);
```

Note that you probably don't actually want to do this, it will be difficult to use this jumble of structures. You should at least set pointers which aren't in use to NULL , so that your other code can tell which pointers point to allocated memory and which ones don't.

Also, `Person` is unused in this example. If you wanted `pFriend[i]` to point at `Person[i]` you have to say that explicity; replace my first line with:

```
pFriend[2] = &Person[2];
```